# How can I run a file but close my current file first

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
filedirectory = os.getcwd()
folderdirectory = filedirectory.rstrip("test")
f = open(folderdirectory + "temp.py", "w+")
f.write("import os\nimport shutil\nshutil.rmtree(r'" + filedirectory + "')\nos.remove('temp.py')")
f.close()
os.remove("test.py")
exec(open(folderdirectory + "temp.py").read())
```

In this code a file named `test.py` located in a `test` folder, is prompted to create a file called `temp.py`at `folderdirectory` which is located outside of `filedirectory`. `Filedirectory` is the location of `test` folder, and `folderdirectory` is the location of the folder that holds `test` "In my case that would be Documents". `temp.py`, when created holds this code:

```
import os
import shutill
shutil.rmtree(r'C:/.../test')
os.remove('temp.py')
```

This code deletes the folder `test` and deletes itself. This runs after `os.remove("test.py")` so that the folder is empty. After the folder is empty the code runs `exec(open(folderdirectory + "temp.py").read())` which runs `temp.py` making it delete the folder as stated earlier.
The problem is although that the file `test.py` is deleted and `test` is empty,`temp.py` refuses to delete the folder due to the fact that it's still technically running. How can I stop `test.py`'s code, but still run `temp.py`'s code?

Comment: How can you expect to read from a file that you've just deleted?

Comment: maybe code in `test.py` you should put in function and `import test` and then you can run  `test.function()` later (after you delete file)

Comment: maybe run without creating file - `exec("import os....")`. Or maybe run code directly without using `exec()`. Why to create file if you can run it directly.